# Upper bound of this fraction?

Tags: calculus, upper-lower-bounds

Do we have an upper bound for $\frac{ax+by+cz}{a_{2} x +b_{2} y +c_2 z}$. What about when $x,y,z<1$ ?

I don't know how to go about it? any tips?

EDIT: Someone kindly presented a counterexample. But are there nice restrictions to put so that it is upper bounded by some parameter. Like can it somehow be upper bounded by say $\frac{a}{a_2}+\frac{b}{b_2}+\frac{c}{c_2}$. (This looks familiar and I've seen it somewhere :) )
Thanks!

Comment: Not in general, for example, $$\dfrac{1x + 0y + 0z}{0x + 1y + 0z} \to \infty$$ as $y \to 0$ with $x$ held constant at something other than zero. Do you want some more restrictions on that?

Comment: Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Numerator and denominator represent two planes , when each is put equal to $d_1, \, d_2$ .

So either they are parallel and there are no common points, or they are coincident, and the ratio is constant everywhere,  or they have a common intersection line where the ratio is $d_1 / d_2$.

Then if you increase $d_1$ the upper plane will move .. and the intersection line will move ..